# Hibernate INSERT with foreign key relation without UPDATE permissions

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two tables *Table A* and *Table B*, Table B has a foreign key to the Table A.
Given a database user with only SELECT and INSERT rights, I need to insert to both tables from my Spring Boot application with Hibernate.

My problem is, that Hibernate generates the following query:

```
SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "Table A" x WHERE "id" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x
```

that needs UPDATE permissions (and the user don't have them). The *FOR KEY SHARE* query should be a lock for the foreign key relation, if I understand it correctly.

My *Table A* entity is annotated with *@Immutable*, but it doesn't seem to work. The *@JoinColumn(updatable = false)* either.

How can I say Hibernate that I don't want this lock?